# How to update RxJS version to a later version in Visual Studio 2015 with an MVC application

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio

Maybe this is a simple question but I downloaded the code for an angular application from this URL
https://github.com/angular/quickstart

Then I copied the files `tslint.json` and `package.json` to the root of my application and also de src folder. After modifying my Layout and `systemjs.config.js` to point to the correct folder 'npm:': '/node_modules/' I am getting the following error.

**Subject' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable**

Following the answers around this problem in StackOverflow, I noticed that RxJS fixed this problem in its later version using as well the latest of typescript. After installing typescript 3.5.3 I decided to change on the package.json its configuration as well

```
"devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "2.5.3"
```

Now let's say that I want to change the rxjs to 5.4.2, how can I do it throw the Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Go to View -> Integrated terminal -> npm install rxjs --save